# Gradle build webapp with does not exist error

Tags: servlets, gradle

I use Gradle to build my web application.
I create src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib to place my jar files named foo.jar
And class in foo.jar is following :

```
package com.foo.util;

class FooUtil {
    public static say() { System.out.println("Hello World"); }
}
```

And in my Servlet, I write following code to use it :

```
import com.foo.util.FooUtil;

...

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    FooUtil.say();
}
```

Finally, I type the following command to build the project :

```
gradle clean build
```

But, I will get the error like following :

```
:clean
:compileJava
package com.foo.util does not exist
import com.foo.util.FooUtil;
```

Following is my build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'
}
```

Do I miss something or do something wrong ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you read http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/war_plugin.html ?

First: it would be better to put your `foo.jar` into other folder like `libs` and then declare it as a compile dependency

`dependencies {
  providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
  compile files('libs/foo.jar')
  ...
}`

Gradle will take care of copying it to proper place in your WAR.

Another thing that you can see in the snippet above is use of `providedCompile` configuration used for Servlet API. This means that your code will compile against this library but it will not be included in the WAR. That's the right way to avoid clash between these classes from your web application and from the servlet container.